# Is there any way to know what trigger call a runnable?

Tags: autosar

I´m new in the Autosar World and I have a question.

I´m working on an app that has several triggers. I would like to know if there is any way to know which one trigger call the runnable wihtout using a static var.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your code, so we can help with what you have tried to far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose the `activationReason` is available. Please have a look at the chapter 4.2.3.3 in the AUTOSAR specification „SWS RTE“.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks.